# After I import "StatusPage" call.response and cause.localizedMessage are not recognized

Tags: kotlin, gradle, server, ktor

```
fun main() {
   embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
       install(StatusPages) {
           exception<IllegalArgumentException> { cause ->
               call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, mapOf("message" to cause.localizedMessage))
           }
           exception<UnknownHostException> { cause ->
               call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, mapOf("message" to cause.localizedMessage))
           }
       }
```

I'm trying to develop my server side app using kotlin/Gradle with Ktor dependencies.
After I import "StatusPage" `call.response` and `cause.localizedMessage` are not recognized, is there an alternative, or am I missing something here, am I using wrong words?

I'm still learning so I really don't know what to do from here, not much info about it.

Answer (score 1):

The block of the `exception` method has two parameters: `ApplicationCall` and `T : Throwable`. To solve the problem, add the `call` parameter:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<IllegalArgumentException> { call, cause ->
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, mapOf("message" to cause.localizedMessage))
        }
        exception<UnknownHostException> { call, cause ->
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, mapOf("message" to cause.localizedMessage))
        }
    }
}
```